# Voltage increases in one outlet when stove is turned on

Tags: stove, voltage

Wife got a new monitor for her laptop and she started noticing that when the burner in the gas stove is turned on, her monitor goes dark for 1-2 seconds. The same happens when the burner is turned off. Her office is next to the kitchen. My office (upper floor, different circuit) doesn't have that problem.

Multimeter in the outlet where her monitor is plugged in shows the voltage spikes from 121V to 160-180V when turning on/off the burner. I assume the monitor has some kind of internal protection, but I am concerned that this may become an issue soon.

Appreciate suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: That sounds bad.  Are there other outlets that change in voltage when this happens? Are the aggressor (stove) and victim (monitor) on the same circuit, or different circuits?

Comment: *"My office (upper floor, different circuit) doesn't have that problem."* Do you mean you don't *notice* equipment going crazy?   Or do you mean you've *checked the voltage* and it's normal 120V?  You would be wise to check voltages all over your house during both "griddle on" and "griddle off".  I gather this is a 120V griddle and not a 240V built-in range?

Comment: *gas stove* That is really strange. Make/model of the stove?

Answer (score 1):

### Voltage Spikes from Stove Ignition

You say you have a *gas* stove, not an electrical stove.

Is it possible that the ignition is interfering with the monitor?

The ignition is activated when the gas knob passes the the beginning of the turn, which occurs when turning on and turning off **(see also below)**.

Perhaps the stove ground is connected to the office ground, but both are not bonded properly. Or maybe it's a bad neutral.

About the voltage spike you mention: if it is a swell in the multimeter reading (swell up to 160V then drop to 120V), that could be from a spike. The peak reading of 160V is a result from inertia of the multimeter internals when measuring voltage spikes. A short ignition style spike may cause that. The number itself doesn't mean much.

Measure the voltage while someone else in the kitchen holds the burner knob in the ignition position. This could help confirm that the swell is related to the ignition.

### Poor Neutral, poor Ground

Check the neutral and ground of the office and stove circuit, they may be shared. I assume the gas stove is plugged into a regular 120V receptacle (a North American "NEMA 5-15" three prong found all over the house).

In the meantime, plug the monitor into a different circuit.

### Gas Safety when Turning Knob OFF

An important aside about fire safety -not related to the question-:

When the knob is "on" without flame, gas fills the room and may ignite upon turning the knob "off". This depends on the stove model, but turning the knob to off does potentially cause a spark.

When we smell gas we are tempted to quickly turn the knob off.

This is fine if it was on for a brief moment, but this is also why in the presence of a gas smell you should **first open windows and doors, wait**, and only then turn the knob "off".

Comment: The ignition is activated when turning the stove OFF?

Comment: @SteveWellens yes, and it is a cause of house fires / gas explosions: when the knob is on without flame, gas fills the room and ignites upon turning off. Depends on stove model, but turning knob to off does potentially cause a spark.

Comment: @SteveWellens I have a family story where I avoided the problem by having someone (I wasn't in the house at the time) pull the plug before turning the gas off. But with a hardwired cooktop (this is one place I *don't* recommend hard-wiring!) or a combination oven/cooktop (even if plug-in, plug is not accessible) that is not an option.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact my fire captain friend tells me they keep the new recruits away from this situation because of the rush to turn the knob, and they first open the windows and wait. BTW, the main or circuit breaker is another option I would think. Pulling plugs is possibly also a source of ignition.

Comment: Done carefully, pulling the plug *on a device that is off at the time* should not be a problem. That is not the case when something is truly powered up or carries a lot of charge (e.g., laptop brick) that ends up causing a spark when you unplug. But yes, that can be a concern. In my case, *at the time* flipping a breaker was not an option as I had old fuse panels, rule of 6 - trying to talk someone who has no clue through what to do would have been pretty much impossible. But yes, with a normal modern panel that is a great idea.